# MSTest: Keep objects across test runs without static variables

Tags: c#, logging, mstest

I'm writing integration tests for a subsystem using MSTest.  This subsystem consists of a couple of service classes that are expensive to setup and tear down, plus some have internal state that I'd like to preserve between test runs.  The obvious fix is to the make the objects static, set them up in the `[ClassInitialize]` method.

However, the services being tested have `TraceSource`s in the objects, and can output very detailed diagnostic messages, which makes debugging broken tests really easy.

The problem is MSTest will only generate output the `TraceSource`s' output for the first `[TestMethod]` ran when running multiple tests.  The output for a test run is empty unless it was the first test ran.

I can't make the service classes instance variables because it takes too long to get them up and going, and I can't make them static variables because I loose the `TraceSource` logging.

Is there a way to keep objects across `[TestMethod]`s without using static variables in MSTest?

Comment: I found a suitable work-around: add a `TextWriterTraceListener` to the `sharedListeners` in `App.config`, and add it to the `TraceSource`s.  I'm still trying to figure out a way to get the `TraceSource`s output to dump into the test runner's standard output.  It's really nice having the all the output from that test run right with the result, and the `TextWriterTraceListener` does not nicely sort the output based on the test.